# Is it a good idea to ask the server for the token every time the user launches the app?

Tags: java, android, token

I have an app , the client wants the user to be logged every time , the problem here is that the token lives only 23 hours, the only approach i came with , is asking the server for the token every time the user opens the app(after he already logged in), but i don't think this is the best solution,can you help me please with an opinion of yours .

[A litle explanation (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSUqW.png)